# Why is a perfectly valid eigen method not working inside a template?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, eigen

In a templated method I have the following line of code:

`Eigen::Vector3f d = start.cast<double>();`

Which does not compile with error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
  115 |             Eigen::Vector3f d = start.cast<double>();
```

This however does compile:

`Eigen::Vector3f d = start;`

Leaving aside the fact that the cast method as I used it is actually defined in eigen. The syntax is fine, if anything the compiler should be telling me that the method does not exist.

This is the stripped down version of the method (that still causes the problem):

```
template<
    typename V,
    typename G,
    typename Vec = decltype(std::declval<V>().position)
>
std::vector<Vec> ComputeGradientLine(
    HMesh<V>& mesh,
    const Vec& start,
    uint face_id,
    const G& gradient)
{
    Eigen::Vector3f d = start.cast<float>();

    return {};
}
```

Comment: `start.template cast<double>();`

Comment: I just tried it, it's breaking the compiler:
`g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.`

Seems it's running out of memory?

Comment: Perhaps it's running out of memory. Certainly you need to provide a [mcve] ...